# How to get a list of JSON objects?

Tags: node.js

I want to get make a list from all the first objects of a .JSON file, like this:

> **list:** object1, object2, object3

Here my .json file example:

```
{
    "object1":["1", "2", "3"],
    "object2": {
        "name": "description"
    },
    "object3": "1"
}
```

Here's my .js code:

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./example.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {

    if (err) throw err;

    const list= JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(list);

});
```

This just outputs the json itself.

[image: output]

Comment: what is the ouput of your console.log

Comment: Just the json itself.

Comment: did you tried `console.log(Object.keys(list))`

Comment: That's what i was lloking for. THANKS! If you want answer it formaly.